# Which game development platform supports Bluetooth connectivity?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am looking for some advice or information to start my 2d mobile game development that supports multi-player using Bluetooth.

I am really new in mobile developing and its hard for me to start, i just want to know which game development platform supports Bluetooth connectivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through this link to understand the Bluetooth connectivity in android and use it in your game for multi-player support.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

This is a link for the type of simple game you are looking. You can go through the source code to understand its working.

https://code.google.com/p/bot-wars/